# Rotating Printing Content using GDI+ Graphics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, draw, gdi+

I am creating a `designsurface` based on this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973830.aspx).

I need to print the document to a printer. I use the following code. All are printing fine.

```
private void pdPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            SizeF sz = e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Size;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(sz.Width, sz.Height);



            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180);
           //draw sample string
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), Brushes.Blue, new RectangleF(50, 50, 100, 75), new StringFormat());
           //draw the objects from designsurface
            designSurfaceCtrl.DrawingObjects.PrintObjects(e.Graphics);


            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-180);

            e.HasMorePages = false;


        designSurfaceCtrl.Invalidate();
    }
```

But when tried to rotate the entire document to 180, only the text Hello is printed.

Other objects which are called inside the `PrintObjects` method is not printing.

Other methods:

```
  public void PrintObjects(Graphics g)
        {


     g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                if (InnerList.Count > 0)
            {
                int i;
                ArrayList jk = new ArrayList();

            for (i = 0; i <= InnerList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                jk.Add(InnerList[i]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i <= jk.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var drawObj = (GraphicObject)jk[i];
                if (drawObj.IsPrintable)
                {
                    drawObj.Draw(g);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Object Draw override:**

```
public override void Draw(Graphics g, bool withBackground = false)
        {
            var gContainer = g.BeginContainer();

            if (AutoSize)
            {
                SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(Account1Text, MFont);
                Width = Convert.ToInt32(mySize.Width);
                Height = Convert.ToInt32(mySize.Height + 2);

                //while printing no need to print background color
                if (withBackground)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(MBackColor), X, Y, Width, Height);

                }

                g.DrawString(Account1Text, MFont, new SolidBrush(MColor), X, Y);


            }
            else
            {
                RectangleF rect1 = new RectangleF(X, Y, Width, Height + 2);

                //while printing no need to print background color
                if (withBackground)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(MBackColor), X, Y, Width, Height);

                }

                g.DrawString(Account1Text, MFont, new SolidBrush(MColor), rect1);


            }
            g.EndContainer(gContainer);
        }
```

Where should I look into?

Comment: I think your `TranslateTransform` is incorrect, try setting it to 1/2 the width and height to rotate it around the center.

Comment: @BradleyUffner But the Hello string is coming properly with the same translatetransform.. it will change for each graphics Draw??

Comment: Do consider that it is *much* simpler to just rotate the piece of paper after you take it out of the printer.  Hehe.

Comment: The translate will a) always have to move to the new center point and b) will add up unless you reset it or translate back after the rotate..

Comment: @HansPassant :) in my case the output of the printer is handled by automatic aligner and conveyors.. that's why..